# polyline that not drawed

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I have a problem with polyline in android
[image]

as you can see in the picture above, it has a line that drawn long to the bottom of my map, but that line is not supposed to be there
[image]

but when I follow that line to the bottom or I zoom out the map like the picture above, the line is gone
is there anyone can help me?

Comment: we could not be able to understand without the stuff which you have tried for this.

Comment: what do you want to know? I'll do my best to provide it

Answer (score 0):

For each vertex (location) in polyline. You can specified the level which will indicate the location that will appear on that level. For example decrease in zoom. If a location does not appear on a given level, then the line will go from the last visible location to the next visible location. Note that the first and last locations must be Level 3 points, otherwise the polyline won't display on all levels.

Check this [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) for more information.

You can use polyline's properties such as points which is the vertices of the line. This line segments are drawn between consecutive points. A polyline is not closed by default; to form a closed polyline, the start and end points must be the same.

Check this [page](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) for the other properties.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite get it. can you explain it more detail?